# Html form with php validation and honeypot

Tags: php, forms, validation, honeypot

Ok here is what I got, I have a web site that is built in html,css,JS. I also have a form on the contact us page, below is the code for the form. Also with this I have a php form validation with a honeypot on it. When I submit the form, if done in 7sec or less it wont submit the form. The time can be adjusted to page loading. The issue I am having is when the submit button is clicked, it goes to a 404 page. I feel the issue is in me action of the form but I am not 100% sure. Any help would be great to understand what is going on here. Thanks

```
<div class="col1 pad_left1">
                        <h2>Contact Form</h2>


                           <form method="post" action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">



                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">

                                <tr valign="top"> 

                                     <td width="20%">
                                     <label for="name">Name:</label>
                                     </td>

                                     <td> 
                                     <input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" id="name" >
                                     </td>

                                 </tr>
                                 <tr valign="top">

                                    <td>
                                    <label for="hotel">Hotel/Company:</label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td> 
                                    <input name="hotel" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" id="hotel" >
                                    </td>

                                  </tr>
                                  <tr valign="top">

                                        <td>
                                       <label for="address">Address:</label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td> 
                                        <input name="hotel" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" id="address" >
                                        </td>

                                   </tr>
                                   <tr valign="top">

                                        <td>
                                        <label for="state">City/State:</label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td> 
                                        <input name="state" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" id="state" >
                                        </td>


                                <tr valign="top"> 

                                    <td>
                                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td> 
                                    <input name="email" type="email" size="40" maxlength="60" id="email" >
                                    </td>

                                 </tr>
                                 <tr valign="top">

                                    <td>
                                    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td> 
                                    <input name="phone" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" id="phone" >
                                    </td>

                                 <tr valign="top"> 

                                     <td>
                                     <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                                     </td>

                                    <td> 
                                    <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="50" id="comments"></textarea>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr> 


                                    <td colspan="2"><div align="center"> 
                                    <div>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="loadtime" value="<?php echo time(); ?>">
                                </div>
                                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

                                        <input name="Reset" type="reset" id="Reset" value="Reset">

                                    </div></td>

                                 </tr>

                         </table>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Spammer can simply modify the hidden var loadtime, and submit like crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually echoing anything out in the action, so it will post to itself - which might be where the 404 is coming from?

Change it to:

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

Note the **=** sign, this will echo the content on the page.

Comment: Ok so with my validation and honeypot on a separate file this will do a check on this file, then if valid, it will send the message, or if it is less than the time it wont send?